# How can I get these bootstrap columns to stack on top of each other?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a cheat-sheet with panels wrapped in size 6 columns, they are all part of the same row.

The problem I'm having is that I want the third column in the row to sit directly underneath the first one.

Instead it behaves 'properly' and forms a second aligned row, where the there is a gap between the first two elements and the row below.

[image]

How can I get the third panel to sit flush against the panel above it?

Comment: Bootstrap doesn't arrange columns like this but you can use [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/extras.html) to achieve this. See this example also > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953248/masonry-with-sidebar-bootstrap/34955089#34955089

Comment: Why don't you make two columns containing two rows instead of two rows  containing two columns?

Answer (score 5):

You can have the rows inside the columns, instead of the columns inside a row. See https://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/89t1g002/1/

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel">Content  </div>
    <div class="panel">Content </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="panel">Content</div>
    <div class="panel">Content</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: so seems like this is really the only way to do it. I was hoping to just be able to throw a bunch of panels on the page and have them stack properly, but this is what I ended up doing.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using twitter bootstrap's grid system. The grid worls with css float and right top floated element won't let the second row's columns to sit inline of the first row. What you want can be done using javascript libraries which provide a system that elements fill the blank spaces no matter what size and number.

I guess you can fulfill the need with [masonry grid system](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonryhorizontal.html).

Comment: A masonry grid may not be possible, but the simple layout the OP asked for is; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/35318158/227299

Answer (score 0):

With you current HTML DOM structure, it is not possible what you wish. But if one modifies the DOM little bit then the desired result can be achived. I have made a [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/ovc7twgu/) here.

Please have a look at the both the codes of Old and New respectively:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h4>
            OLD
        </h4>
        <div id="div1" class="cols col-xs-6">
            <h2>
                Div 1
            </h2>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="div2" class="cols col-xs-6">
            <h2>
                Div 2
            </h2>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="div3" class="cols col-xs-6">
            <h2>
                Div 3
            </h2>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="div4" class="cols col-xs-6">
            <h2>
                Div 4
            </h2>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>


<div class="sep">

</div>



<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h4>
            NEW
        </h4>
        <div class="cols col-xs-6">
            <h2>
                Div 1
            </h2>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cols  col-xs-6">
            <h2>
                Div 2
            </h2>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="cols  col-xs-6">
            <h2>
                Div 3
            </h2>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="cols  col-xs-6">
            <h2>
                Div 4
            </h2>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>
            <div>
                Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.cols {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.sep{
  border: 2px solid;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: You should explain in words what the modification is; we have to read too much code when you could explain what you did in a single sentence

Answer (score 0):

As @Farzad YZ says, bootstrap does not do that kind of arrangement, but there are many plugins based on javascript that will help you to achieve your goal. I recomend to you this: http://salvattore.com/

This plugin works perfectly with the ***responsive*** concept

Answer (score 0):

Another (possibly simple) option would be to nest your columns and rows. See [Grid Nesting](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting). You can use two `col-sm-6` as your main columns and place however many a new row in each with as many `col-sm-12` columns as needed.

See example Snippet.

```css
body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
code {
  border-radius: 3px
}
.bs-callout+.bs-callout {
  margin-top: -5px
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <section class="col-sm-6">

      <div class="row">
        <section class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <b>ONE</b>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetti.</p>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>List files matching a pattern</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </section>

        <section class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <b>TWO</b>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>List files matching a pattern</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>List files matching a pattern</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </section>

        <section class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <b>THREE</b>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard .</p>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </section>

      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="col-sm-6">

      <div class="row">

        <section class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <b>FOUR</b>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </section>

        <section class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <b>FIVE</b>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy tex.</p>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </section>

        <section class="col-sm-12">

          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of <b>SIX</b>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
              <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped">
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td><code>To switch directories, type</code>
                  </td>
                  <td>To switch directories, type</td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>

        </section>

      </div>
    </section>

  </div>
</div>
```